Summary per year in SSRS
I am working in SSRS.
I would like to see a summary yearly of meter readings.
To get the year I used this expression:
=Year(Fields!VerbruikStartdatum.Value)

And for the sum of the meter readings I used this calculation:
=IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sum(Fields!Gecorrigeerd_Verbruik.Value)), 0, Sum(Fields!Gecorrigeerd_Verbruik.Value))

But is does not give a sum per year
2020  15  0
2020  20  0
2021  22  15 
2021  23  30

[Summary yearly pictureenter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/2f1BAlIM.png)
Summary per year
enter image description here
Year    Meter reads
2020    0
2021    83 73
2022    763 780


Edit your question and show your report design. This should be easy, you need to have a row group that groups by year or group by an expression that returns the year so you original expression should be fine as a group expression =Year(Fields!VerbruikStartdatum.Value). When you share your design, make sure you show the row groups pane under the main designer and show how the row groups are configured, then it should be easy to answer.
